# What are the latest DeBayer/Demosaicing technics

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing

In an effort to improve the image quality I'm getting from a camera I started digging up alternative demosaicing technics. I found out that there are allot of different algorithms but most of them are dated back to 2000. Since more than a decade has passed, I was wondering what are the latest technics around?

Algorithm or source code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Gilad, I'd be glad to know as well. Most of the existing solutions are propriatery and not published. Wikipedia provides a number of recent references.

Comment: I agree, most companies understand that even a patent won't be good in defending their algorithms. I'm sure that some of the latest methods are known and published.

Comment: You might want to ask in the Signal Processing forum as well: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the most recent work, but the results are a good improvement over classic algorithms: http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/bcms_self_similarity_driven_demosaicking/

And you can explore the site for more algorithms and examples, with online demos and source code (open source licences). It should help you getting started.

Answer (score 1):

Not latest, published in 2007, the demosaicing with [DFPD](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4032820) (Directional Filtering and a posteriori Decision) seems to give the best result. Not only it removes the artifacts at high frequency regions, it produces more crisp and natural colors than previous approaches.

This [blog post](https://blog.cuvilib.com/2014/06/12/dfpd-debayer-on-gpu/) compares the DFPD approach with hq bilinear interpolation and the result is quite obvious: DFPD reconstructs the image with better colors and without artifacts.